# NestJS/GraphQL/Local Auth - How to define variables passed in

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs

What is the standard approach to defining variables to be used only in guards/interceptors?

Resolver

- Without the `@Args()` it throws an error when I send a mutation with variables
- With the `@Args()`, it has an eslint error `createUserInput' is defined but never used`

```js
@UseGuards(GqlLocalAuthGuard)
@Mutation(() => User)
async login(
  // @Args("createUserInput") createUserInput: CreateUserInput, 
  // ^ it works if I put this
): Promise<User> {
  return { id: "1", email: "fake@gmail.com" };
}
```

GqlLocalAuthGuard

- This extends local auth guard and the strategy verifies that the user put in the correct password

```js
export class GqlLocalAuthGuard extends AuthGuard("local") {
  getRequest(context: ExecutionContext): any {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    const req = ctx.getContext().req;
    const { createUserInput } = ctx.getArgs<any>();
    req.body = createUserInput;
    return req;
  }
}
```

Error without `Args()`

```
"GraphQLError: Unknown argument \"createUserInput\" on field \"Mutation.login\"."
```

Mutation

```js
mutation ($createUserInput: CreateUserInput!) {
  login (createUserInput: $createUserInput) {
    id,
    email,
  } 
}
```